# Swift structs an protocols not work as expected

Tags: swift

Following playground-ready code ;)

```
protocol Prot {
    static func instanceArray() -> [Self]
}

struct A {
    init() {
        // Do something
    }
}

extension A: Prot {
    static func instanceArray() -> [A] {
        return [A(), A()]
    }
}

func work() -> [Prot] {
    return A.instanceArray()
}
```

The compiler will throw an error at `return A.instanceArray()`: *Cannot convert return expression of type [A] to return type [Prot]*

Why is the compiler not able to convert these types even though `A` implements the protocol `Prot`? 
I know that a workaround is to change the return type of `instanceArray()` to `[Prot]` but I don't really like this solution.
Is this a compiler bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to see what's going on if we eliminate all the extra stuff not needed in your example. So, consider this:

```
protocol Prot {}
struct A : Prot {}

let arr = [A(), A()] // 1: ok
let arr2 = [A(), A()] as [Prot] // 2: ok
let arr3 = arr as [Prot] // 3: compile error
```

The question is then, why is [2] legal but [3] is not? The difference is that we are allowed to *form* an array of A instances and type it as a `[Prot]`, but we are not allowed to *cast* an existing array variable, already typed as `[A]`, to a `[Prot]`.

You can call this a bug or a limitation of Swift if you want to, and you would certainly be justified in a filing a bug report, but in any case it's a well-known shortcoming having to do with the fact that protocols are just not quite full-fledged types.

Comment: Well covered, I think, by Rob Napier's answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Answer (score 2):

There is a away to get around it if you must

```
func work() -> [Prot] {
    return A.instanceArray().map{ $0 as Prot }
}
```